# Get the referral source url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a Laravel-newbie and have got the following piece of code in my landing page:

```
Route::get('/prelaunch', [ 'uses' => 'SubscriptionController@getReferrer', 'as' => 'subscriber.referral'], function () {
    return view('prelaunch');
});
```

What I would like to do, is to read a field such as "utm_source" from the url and store take some actions against it, such as counting the users that land into the page from twitter, fb etc.

Any suggestions on this one?

**UPDATE**

For example: the user lands on `localhost/landing_page?utm_source=google`
when they come from google.
What I need in this case is to read `utm_source` value and e.g. increase the count of the users that came from "google". Hope that helps a little bit.

Comment: can you explain your problem in more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Laravel 5, then you can get the query string parameters using this `Input::all()` will give all inputs/get/post variable while `Input::get('utm_source')` will give you specific value... in your route, before this line `return view('prelaunch');` write this `print_r(Input::all());` and how me response.

Answer (score 1):

If you're pointing your route to a controller you're logic should be in your controller, e.g.

routes.php

```
Route::get('/prelaunch', [ 
    'uses' => 'SubscriptionController@getReferrer',
    'as' => 'subscriber.referral'
]);
```

SubscriptionController.php

```
public function getReferrer() {
    $utm = \Input::get('utm_source');
    // Do whatever you need to with it here
    return view('prelaunch');
}
```